# Simple ajax and jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple facebook [app](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Trololo/236069739747588?sk=app_222001914503807).

Using some jquery `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=' +  
          encodeURI(query) + '&access_token=' + accessToken +'&format=json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});

result: `[Object { uid1="100002251534328", uid2="708404079"}]`
```

Why can't I type `response.uid1` to get `uid1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that response is array containing objects. Instead of `response.uid1` try to use `response.get(0).uid1`